# loading spatialite extension to sqlite3 in python on windows

Tags: python, sqlite, gis

I'm trying to set up an application with an sqlite database on windows, using python, and I need the spatialite extension.

I have the mod_spatialite binaries downloaded.

```py
import os; import sys
import sqlite3

spatialite_path = r"folder\with\binaries"
os.environ['PATH'] = spatialite_path + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
sys.path = [spatialite_path] + sys.path

conn = sqlite3.Connection(':memory:')
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.load_extension('mod_spatialite') # fails
conn.load_extension('mod_spatialite.dll') # fails
conn.load_extension(os.path.join(spatialite_path,'mod_spatialite.dll')) #fails
os.chdir(spatialite_path); assert os.path.exists('mod_spatialite.dll'); conn.load_extension('mod_spatialite') # fails
```

For all, the process fails with:

> OperationalError: The specified module could not be found.

Python version 3.10, sqlite3 version 2.6, mod_spatialite version 5.0.1.

EDIT:

This problem appears to be a compatibility issue between Spatialite 5.0.1 and python 3.10.11

EDIT#2:

The code above works perfectly well with the python 3.8.10 installation provided with the Spyder IDE, but does not work with a clean python 3.8.10 installation in a virtual environment.

It also works with the python 3.9.11 that came with ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the path to the spatialite binaries to your PATH environment variable manually, not through the code.
You probably don't even need the `import spatialite` statement.
lastly, use your third option (`conn.load_extension(os.path.join(spatialite_path,'mod_spatialite.dll'))`) to load the extension. If that doesn't work, try to provide the actual string path to the `load_extension` method. And make sure to restart your IDE after adding to your PATH.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working for me. After adding the path to the binaries to my path envir variable, I still get `OperationalError: The specified module could not be found.`

My code still passes these assertions: 
`assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(spatialite_path,'mod_spatialite.dll'))
assert spatialite_path in os.environ['PATH'].split(';')`

Comment: Check the permissions to the spatialite binaries folder and make sure everyone has read/write access to it.
Also do you mind describing the steps you took to add the binaries folder to your PATH? Add a screenshot if you can.

Comment: Where do you have that  spatialite binaries folder on your system anyway? Because you may not be able to chance those permissions depending on that location.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. Permissions are all correct. 
Interestingly, the procedure I show above works as intended in Python 3.8.10, though not in Python 3.10.11, which is the distribution I am currently working with.

Comment: Ah, that could be it. I work with Python 3.8.7. When I ran into this issue and before I added the SpatiaLite binaries folder to my PATH, I saw reports of incompatibility between Python versions and distributions of SpatiaLite. It may be that you need to compile it from source with the right options (I hear that's not trivial though) But maybe check on their website and the community there for help with Python version incompatibility. [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index)